# Powershell get several specifics user in AD

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to figure how do i do a query that will get in AD with powershell.

Get multiple specifics users using samaccountname like 10 users per examples.

Anyone can give me lead where to start.

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried? what did not work as expected? please, show us that you tried something ... [*grin*]

Comment: Take a look at [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps)

Comment: Open the Windows Server ADAC - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/get-started/adac/introduction-to-active-directory-administrative-center-enhancements--level-100- - Click thru the GUI and let it write the baseline code for you - https://www.petri.com/use-active-directory-administrative-center-create-powershell-commands - that you can later tweak as needed.

Comment: i did that but it work "Get-ADUser -Filter { (surname -eq 'eng') -or (surname -eq 'benz') -or (surname -eq 'gray')" but should i do it a different way?